# CoreBluetooth with C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, core-bluetooth

I need to send data via bluetooth from iOS app into a C++ application. So
I have to implement Bluetooth module in c++, in iOS app using Corebluetooth framework.I created a wrapper class of bluetooth module for C++ app. I can call the iOS function from C++ application but, C++ doesn't have Corebbluetooth. Is it possible to create wrapper class for corebluetooth to use with C++ ?
If possible how to create the same?

Comment: there are other Bluetooth libraries for several platforms, you just have to google.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

You just need to create an Objective-C++ wrapper that forwards the messages to your C++ code. Objective-C++ allows you to use C++ code in your Objective-C classes. To use it, you either need to set the extensions of source files with your Objective-C wrapper from `.m` to `.mm` or set the sources to `Objective-C++` in the File Inspector in Xcode.